# How to avoid templated virtual methods?

Tags: c++, templates

I got stuck with implementing the following functionality:

```
class Based {
  public:
    template <typename T> void foo(T t) { boo(t); }
    template <typename T> virtual void boo(T t) = 0; // Error!
 };

class Derived : public Based {
  public:
    template <typename T> void boo(T t) {
      std::cout<<"Derived::boo called\n";
    }
};

int main() {

  Derived derived;
  derived.foo(0);
  derived.foo('c');
  //etc.
}
```

I know that C++ does not allow to use virtual templated methods, but can not see any other way to do this. 
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The usual solution in this situation involves a type erasure-based approach of some sort. The actual solution depends on each individual situation. There is no universal answer that will work in every situation. This question does not provide sufficient detail in order to form an answer. The given example does not provide sufficient detail. Most likely, [this is an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You can use class template instead. Declare your class as template. Use the type passed to class instance in your class methods. This way u can get a pure virtual function also with template.

Comment: @sagar, thank you! I think this is exactly what I need.

Comment: CRTP and static dispatch might help.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes I have found this solution.

```
template <typename X>
class Based {
  public:
    template <typename T> void foo(T t) { static_cast<X *>(this)->boo(t); }
};

class Derived : public Based<Derived> {
  public:
    template <typename T> void boo(T t) {
      std::cout<<"Derived::boo called\n";
    }
};

int main() {

  Derived derived;
  derived.foo(0);
  derived.foo('c');
  //etc.
}
```

Thank you for suggestions!